# Данный тип CollectionView не поддерживает изменения в своем SourceCollection из потока, отличного от потока Dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

Есть вот такой код клиента:

```
private void btChangeState_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsConnected)
    {
        Exception error = null;

        if (!TryConnect($"net.tcp://{tbIP.Text}:{tbPort.Text}/JobService", out Proxy, out error))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Proxy.Close();
    }

    IsConnected = !IsConnected;
    Jobs.Clear();
}

private bool TryConnect(string endpoint, out JobServiceClient proxy, out Exception error)
{
    try
    {
        var callback = new ClientCallback();
        callback.GiveJob += Callback_GiveJobAsync;
        var ctx = new InstanceContext(callback);
        proxy = new JobServiceClient(ctx);
        proxy.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(endpoint);
        proxy.Connect();
        error = null;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        proxy = null;
        error = e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Почему при вызове Connect у меня падает такая ошибка? "Данный тип CollectionView не поддерживает изменения в своем SourceCollection из потока, отличного от потока Dispatcher." Никакие дополнительные потоки в данном случае не используются, все в основном.

Сейчас доперло отлаживать не клиент на котором ошибка выскакивает, а сервер, где собственно и вызывается функция Connect через прокси. Походу ошибка именно там. Но почему она выскакивает я все равно не понимаю... В контракте сервиса есть коллекция `public ObservableCollection<ClientView> Clients { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ClientView>();`. В функции Connect как раз создается объект ClientView и добавляется в нее. И именно при этом добавлении (согласно отладчику) падает ошибка, которая просто передается клиенту. Но все происходит в одном потоке, никаких лишних потоков там нет! Откуда же ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

Как выяснилось опытным путем проблема была в том что кнопка запускающая сервер имела асинхронный обработчик. Не понятно совершенно как, но как то он влиял на это, поскольку стоило сделать его синхронным, как ошибка пропала.

Comment: Task.Run() возможно, он выполняет содержимое в гарантированно НЕ UIном потоке

Answer (score 2):

Все-таки проверьте еще раз. С виду, кажется, что это обычная проблема для WPF приложений - изменение UI компонентов вне основного потока UI. Возможно Вы изменяете объект в коллбеке, а коллбек вызывается в другом потоке. Это можно легко проверить. Попробуйте вызывать коллбек используя Dispatcher изменяемого компонента:

```
   component.Dispatcher.Invoke(callback)
```

Comment: да нет вроде. И код не помог, та же ошибка и с ним.

Comment: WCF вызывает методы callback там где надо, проблема не в этом

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov чет ничего не понял... Кто вызывает? Где вызывает? Зачем вызывает? В чем проблема???